# iPhone - Objective-C NSURL Memory Leaks galore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection, core-foundation

I am getting the following memory leak when using `NSURL`. I use this method in quite a few different places and receive memory leaks all the time using the Leaks instruments.

Object Management:

```
self.objManager = [[HJObjManager alloc] init];
NSString *cacheDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Caches/App"];
HJMOFileCache *fileCache = [[[HJMOFileCache alloc] initWithRootPath:cacheDirectory] autorelease];
self.objManager.fileCache = fileCache;
fileCache.fileCountLimit = 100;
fileCache.fileAgeLimit = 60*60*24;
[fileCache trimCacheUsingBackgroundThread];
```

Where it's used:

```
HJManagedImageV *mi = [[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myHeaderView.profilePictureImageView.bounds.origin.x,
                                                                         self.myHeaderView.profilePictureImageView.bounds.origin.y,
                                                                         self.myHeaderView.profilePictureImageView.bounds.size.width,
                                                                         self.myHeaderView.profilePictureImageView.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];

mi.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
mi.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
mi.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
mi.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

mi.url = [NSURL URLWithString:profilePictureUrl];
[mi showLoadingWheel];

[self.myHeaderView.profilePictureImageView addSubview:mi];
[self.objManager manage:mi];
```

Dealloc:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.tv = nil;
    self.friends = nil;
    self.sortedFriends = nil;
    self.detailView = nil;
    self.profileView = nil;
    self.objManager = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tv release];
    [friends release];
    [sortedFriends release];
    [detailView release];
    [profileView release];
    [objManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have `NSZombieEnabled` set to `YES`?

Comment: Yes, I do actually. Is that going to cause issues with Leaks in Instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stack trace to determine the place of leak.

Edit:

make sure you are releasing the mi.url in dealloc method:

```
-(void) dealloc {
   //some other releases
   self.url = nil;

   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: url is a property for HJManagedImageV. I initialise it this way: HJManagedImageV *mi = [[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)] autorelease]; See my updated code above.

Comment: Yes, but make sure that all the HJManagedImageV's ivars are released properly. BTW post the code of [self.objManager manage:mi]. It seems that mi is retained there, but never released.

Comment: I have updated the code above to include [self.objManager manage:mi] and also my dealloc method.

Comment: Is objManager property is declared as retain? If yes, then you have a leak here: self.objManager = [[HJObjManager alloc] init];   Change it like this:  self.objManager = [[[HJObjManager alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: self.objManager is declared as (nonatomic, retain).

Comment: I get an error that's it's already been released if I change it to self.objManager = [[[HJObjManager alloc] init] autorelease]; !

Comment: It means that you're over releasing  self.objManager somewhere in your code.

Comment: Hmm, if you use autorelease does that mean you still need to release in the dealloc method? I think dealloc is getting called and it's releasing it in there.

Comment: You can check: the retain count of self.objManager would be 2 after this line: self.objManager = [[HJObjManager alloc] init];

Comment: I removed self.objManager and used objManager instead and made sure it was in the dealloc method getting released.

Comment: can you also answer the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860576/how-to-remove-parsing-and-nsplaceholdermutablestring-frame-leaks-in-iphone. thanks in advance